# Mutex vs busy wait for tcp io

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, tcp, mutex

I do not care about being a cpu hog as I have one thread assigned to each core and the system threads blocked off to their own set. My understanding is that mutex is of use when other tasks are to run, in this case that is not important so I am considering having a consumer thread loop on an address in memory waiting for its value to be non zero - as in the single producer thread that is looping recv()ing with TCP_NONBLOCK set just deposited information and it is now non zero.

Is my implantation a smart one given my circumstances or should I be using a mutex or custom interrupt even though no other tasks will run.

Comment: In absence of a good reason to do so, it's stupid to call `recv` in a loop with `TCP_NONBLOCK`. Just use a blocking `recv` unless you have something else to do in the loop between retries, but since you're using threads, you shouldn't have to do that.

Comment: Agree with R's comment, and also waiting for receive buffer to be nonzero is a poor design because you can't tell the difference between not receiving anything and receiving data that is zeroes.

Comment: Ah but I have tricks to check the msg is done, so what is the prob?

Comment: And i could possibly do something else like clear the old data while i loop waiting for more, or i could just have another thread handle it

Comment: I really don't think you have any idea what you're doing. Everything you've mentioned doing (pinning threads to cpus, nonblocking io, "custom interrupt", ...) with no motivation for why you're doing it screams *Cargo Culting*.

Comment: Low latency, single application (dedicated cores), what more could you want?

Comment: There is a specific need for what i asked, i beleive there should be a reasonable answer, for a programmer with the right experience.

Comment: There is *no* 'specific need' to spin reading a socket in non-blocking mode, which is what these gentlemen are addressing. You should either use blocking mode or use select() to tell you when data is ready to be read in non-blocking mode.

Comment: @EJP ok your getting to the root of my understanding, now why is your proposal lower layency, i beleive what the posters are describing is for best efficiency i need best latency.

Comment: What makes you think looping in a non blocking recv is better with respect to latency than select or blocking recv ?

Comment: Just go the way you want, and come back when you have a real problem. Implement your solution, see if it solves your problem, eventually come back here if your problem is not solved, and let us now what is not solved. Producer / consumer is handled with a mutex guarded fifo, and a semaphore to wake the consumer. The mutex is to ensure producer and consumer won't touch the fifo at the same time.

Comment: @user417896 How is burning the CPU instead of letting it do something else going to improve latency?

Comment: No need to run any other process on that core, might as well loop checking a variable than syscall or poll

Comment: I agree with R and EJP above, but also, you seem to be thinking that burning a core is "free." Doing so will cause the CPU to burn more power, which costs more in its own right, plus it will kick the CPU's fan up to a higher speed and probably still increase the junction temp of the CPU die, which will reduce both their useful lifetimes. All of this might only amount to a few hundred dollars a year, but add on top of that the eventual downtime when you have to replace that server early. Plus, it means you're probably burning another server or three that could be co-hosted in a VM on this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to points by @ugoren and comments by others:

Even if you have a valid use-case for busy-waiting and burning a core, which are admittedly rare, you need to:

- Protect the data shared between threads. This is where locks come into play - you need [**`mutual exclusion`**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion) when accessing any complex shared data structure. People tend to look into [**`lock-free`**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock-free) algorithms here, but these are way-way not obvious and error-prone and are still considered deep black magic. Don't even try these until you have a solid understanding of concurrency.
- Notify threads about changed state. This is where you'd use [**`conditional variables`**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_%28synchronization%29) or monitors. There are other methods too, [`eventfd(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/eventfd.2.html) on Linux, for example.

Here are some links for you to show that it's much harder then you seem to think:

- [Memory Ordering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_ordering)
- [Out-of-order execution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out-of-order_execution)
- [ABA problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABA_problem)
- [Cache coherence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_coherence)

Answer (score 2):

Busy-wait can give you a lower latency and somewhat better performance in some cases.

Letting other threads use the CPU is the obvious reason not to do it, but there are others:

1. You consume more power. An idle CPU goes into a low power state, reducing consumption very significantly. Power consumption is a major issue in data centers, and any serious application must bit waste power.
2. If your code runs in a virtual machine (and everything is being virtualized these days), your machine competes for CPU with others. Consuming 100% CPU leaves less for the others, and may cause the hypervisor to give your machine less CPU when it's really needed.
3. You should always stick to mainstream methods, unless there's a good reason not to. In this case, the mainstream is to use `select` or `poll` (or `epoll`). This lets you do other stuff while waiting, if you want, and doesn't waste CPU time. Is the performance difference large enough to justify busy wait?

Comment: Exactly my points I have a specialized software running only itself and the os, I could care less about power, please the datacenter costs a few hundred a month anyway!  Thanks for the answer I want the fastest and I see a way to implement, will be going rebel ;)